# Can you setup UART Reception on dsPIC33EP512MU814 on eval board dsPICDEM MCLV-2

Tags: pic, uart

According to microchip, the [dsPIC33EP512MU814](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=dsPIC33EP512MU814) can be integrated with the [dsPICDEM MCLV-2 Development Board](http://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=DM330021-2) using [dsPIC33EP512MU814 Plug-In-Module](http://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=MA330025-3)

However, according to the [dsPICDEM MCLV-2 Interface map](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/DS-52080a.pdf) the UART Rx and Tx of the evaluation board are pins 49 and 50, respectively. So then according to [plug-in-module interface map](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIM_814_144infosheet.pdf) that UART Rx must be mapped to pin `SDA2/RP100/RF4`, and UART Tx must be mapped to `SCL2/RP101/RF5`.

I'm aware that you can map out UART Tx to RP101 by simply assigning

```
RPOR9BITS.RP101R = 1;
```

However I was expecting the pin of UART Rx to be RPIx not an RPx.

Does this mean you can't perform UART Reception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the datasheet (emphasis mine):

> The number of available pins is dependent on the particular device and
>   its pin count. Pins that support the Peripheral Pin Select feature
>   include the designation “RPn” or “RPIn” in their full pin designation,
>   where “RP” designates a remappable function ***for input or output*** and
>   “RPI” designates a remappable functions for input only, and “n” is the
>   remappable pin number.

Since an "RPx" pin can be either input or output, you can remap the UART Rx to it.

```
RPINR18 = 0x0064;      // UART Rx PPS -> RP100
```